# CKeditor on Textarea implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I have implemented a CKeditor from the below link:-

[CKEditor](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11819/) But the issue is that, As soon as I register the editor on my page, it gets reflected. I want the same editor just only for my asp.net textbox. What should I do and make change so that It can only be visible to my textbox only. Please help.

See my textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostdesc" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Are you using script or the dll for the ckeditor?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan: Yes, using the dll.

Comment: So in that case why you need the textbox instead you can simply use `CKEditorControl` as the mentioned article says and just change the name of that like "txtPostdesc".

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan: can you please write the syntax or code for it, as I haven't used that before. In the answer section, so I can mark it answer if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the article [CKEditor in ASP.Net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11819/) it described the way of implementing CKEditor with dll.

You would require following things

```
1. Two dll : CkEditor.dll and CKEditor.NET.dll.
2. CKEditor folder containing all js, css and images.
```

Register the `CKEditor` control at the top of your .aspx page such as

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
```

Now you will be able to write the CKEditor server control markup such as below

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtPostdesc" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

In above I just change the ID as per your textarea ID. Now you can set and get its content via `.Text` Property in your code behind file i.e.

```
string str = txtPostdesc.Text;
```

Hope above explanation works for you.

Comment: but I have already used the ID for the textbox, So can I give this ID again ?

Comment: remove your textbox as the CKEditor Control will do this for you.

Comment: i am getting error as, *The ID 'txtPostdesc' is already used by another control.* even after removing the textbox. Note: I want that value to get stored in the table, so I am calling in the code-behind also as `cmd1.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPostdesc.Text;`

Comment: Can you check if you are not using the same id for a differ control?

Comment: yes, I checked the whole thing and i am sure, i am not using it for different control.

Comment: Hmmm, can you share your pages like (.aspx and .aspx.cs)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65876/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-kundan-singh-chouhan).

Comment: Can you please check it